# Javascript Visual Studio Intellisense Not Working On One Project

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, intellisense

For some reason, the Javascript intellisense isn't working in Visual Studio for just one project.  It's an existing project, and if I open up others or create a new one, my Javascript intellisense works fine, just not on this one project.  I get C# intellisense, just not Javascript.

Any ideas?  I've tried resetting VS settings, deleting the .suo file, rebooting, etc.  There's gotta be something specific with this project that is preventing this from working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found out there was a conflict in my _references.js.  In my case, this happened when I installed Kendo via the Upgrade Wizard part of Visual Studio.

I left a reference to kendo.all.min.js in my _references.js, and removed everything else.  As that all file has everything.

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Well done you. I had the same issue and had tried everything to "fix" visual studio. Thanks for posting the solution for everyone else to benefit from.

Answer (score 0):

After Deleting _references.js from JScripts folder, it start working for me..